# how to use two kinds of font-family in one page?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I have web pages that has two kinds of language,english and chinese,i only can apply one font-family to one language,how can i apply two kinds of font-family to both english and chinese at same time?any ideas?

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Kavoon';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(http://example.com/myfonts.eot);
  src: local('Kavoon Regular'), local('Kavoon-Regular'), url(http://example.com/myfonts.eot) format('embedded-opentype'), url(http://example.com/myfonts.woff) format('woff');
}
```

how to change this definitions to support my requirement?

Comment: You can create another font face with other language. Add how you apply this font to elements. So we get complete picture.

Comment: you mean define two font-face? will they conflict each other?

Comment: use different font-family name.

Comment: ok,let me have a try,and i download font from google[link](https://www.google.com/fonts/) there is only ttf format,where can i get woff and eot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer of Code Lord is the correct one but always try to convert your fonts for each browser:

English:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'english';
    src: url('english.eot');
    src: url('english.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('english.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('english.woff') format('woff'),
         url('english.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('english.svg#english_medregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Chinese:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'chinese';
    src: url('chinese.eot');
    src: url('chinese.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('chinese.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('chinese.woff') format('woff'),
         url('chinese.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('chines.svg#chinese_medregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

You can convert your fonts with this tool: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Comment: what about otf ?i have ever used it before,it can not convert otf format

Comment: That does not matter. When you use a font (or download a free font from the internet) most of the time the font is in a .ttf file format. There might be a change that the font is available as an .otf, if so put it in the converter and you will get the right css styles for that format if you have both you can just add them to your css. Have a look at this topic for more info: http://superuser.com/questions/96390/difference-between-otf-open-type-or-ttf-true-type-font-formats

Comment: If I look at your code I see that you use the "kavoon" font family. If you download your font here: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/kavoon and use it in the generator it converts it properly.

Comment: Ok,i will dive into it,Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create another font face for different fonts.

English :

```
 @font-face {
font-family: EnglishFont;
src: url(source_to_english.woff);
}
```

chinese:

```
 @font-face {
font-family: chineseFont;
src: url(source_to_chinese.woff);
}
```

Other:

```
 @font-face {
font-family: OtherFont;
src: url(source_to_other.woff);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's a service based in Taiwan can help you use different Chinese font.

http://en.justfont.com/fonts

Due to the large size of Chinese font file, it's recommended to use Google cloud service. But there's no appropriate Chinese font on it. So you can give it a try on this justfont web font service.

1. Select any font you want for specific font weight. Then it'll be added to your project.
2. Choose your selector like `.notosans`, `#notosans` or `h2`
3. Click "JS" button and get your code for your setting
4. Add it before `<body>`
5. Insert your class or id.

Give it a try and get your beautiful Chinese font by using class and id. :)

Comment: yup,thanks, google has chinese font named [google font](https://www.google.com/get/noto/#/)**Noto Sans CJK SC** ,it has a size of 16 MB almost,and google is forbidden in china